# python twisted - Timeouting on a sent message that did not get a response

Tags: python, timeout, client, twisted

I am creating a sort of a client-server implementation, and I'd like to make sure that every sent message gets a response. So I want to create a timeout mechanism, which doesn't check if the message itself is delivered, but rather checks if the delivered message gets a response.

IE, for two computers 1 and 2:

```
1: send successfully: "hello"
2: <<nothing>>
...
1: Didn't get a response for my "hello" --> timeout
```

I thought of doing it by creating a big boolean array with id for each message, which will hold a "in progress" flag, and will be set when the message's response is received.

I was wondering perhaps there was a better way of doing that.

Thanks,
Ido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a better way, which funnily enough I myself [just implemented here](http://www.mail-archive.com/twisted-python@twistedmatrix.com/msg04777.html). It uses the [TimeoutMixin](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.policies.TimeoutMixin.html) to achieve the timeout behaviour you need, and a [DeferredLock](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredLock.html) to match up the correct replies with what was sent.

```
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.protocols.policies import TimeoutMixin
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineOnlyReceiver

class PingPongProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver, TimeoutMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = defer.DeferredLock()
        self.deferred = None

    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        result = self.lock.run(self._doSend, msg)
        return result

    def _doSend(self, msg):
        assert self.deferred is None, "Already waiting for reply!"

        self.deferred = defer.Deferred()
        self.deferred.addBoth(self._cleanup)
        self.setTimeout(self.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
        self.sendLine(msg)
        return self.deferred

    def _cleanup(self, res):
        self.deferred = None
        return res

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.deferred:
            self.setTimeout(None)
            self.deferred.callback(line)
        # If not, we've timed out or this is a spurious line

    def timeoutConnection(self):
        self.deferred.errback(
            Timeout("Some informative message"))
```

I haven't tested this, it's more of a starting point. There are a few things you might want to change here to suit your purposes:

1. I use a [LineOnlyReceiver](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineOnlyReceiver.html) — that's not relevant to the problem itself, and you'll need to replace `sendLine`/`lineReceived` with the appropriate API calls for your protocol.
2. This is for a serial connection, so I don't deal with `connectionLost` etc. You might need to.
3. I like to keep state directly in the instance. If you need extra state information, set it up in `_doSend` and clean it up in `_cleanup`. Some people don't like that — the alternative is to create nested functions inside `_doSend` that close over the state information that you need. You'll still need that `self.deferred` there though, otherwise `lineReceived` (or `dataReceived`) has no idea what to do.

### How to use it

Like I said, I created this for serial communications, where I don't have to worry about factories, connectTCP, etc. If you're using TCP communications, you'll need to figure out the extra glue you need.

```
# Create the protocol somehow. Maybe this actually happens in a factory,
# in which case, the factory could have wrapper methods for this.
protocol = PingPongProtocol()
def = protocol.sendMessage("Hi there!")
def.addCallbacks(gotHiResponse, noHiResponse)
```